# How to get a Button's background back to default (programmatically)?

Tags: android, button

So I'm setting a button's background doing this:

```
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button1);
```

How do I programmatically set it back to the default (boring grey) Android button? Is there a R.android.boring_grey resource identifier I can reference without recreating those states myself? Couldn't seem to find it. Maybe my Googling skills are failing me.

Oh and by the way I tried this:

```
   b.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

And the button actually disappeared (blended with black background?).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
android.R.drawable.btn_default;
```

Comment: That's the one, thanks. Couldn't find it for the life of me. Saw a previous post about this, but they left off the "android.R" part and just had "R.drawable"

Comment: The answer below suits people who have initially customised their buttons differently.

Comment: Is there any way to get the system default button instead of what looks like the Gingerbread default button?

Comment: This did not work as the btn_default may is not always the default for your app! I used @piotrpo's answer and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 21):

first get the default background of `Button b;` using

```
Drawable d = b.getBackground();
```

then set another background of your choice

```
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button1);
```

if you need default background again use this

```
b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Comment: I would say this answer is better then the accepted one. The accepted answer gave me a android 2.3 style button, while this gave me exactly the original button (which it is way more likely to do then the accepted answer).

Comment: thank you so much for this answer! I searched for a proper solution for so long, and finally found it here. this is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Since btn_default is not the default for every app, I used this answer. Not the accepted one!

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
b.tr.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Comment: the method setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated

Comment: use setBackground(Drawable) instead

Answer (score 2):

I did it by

> this.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);

Answer (score 1):

try

```
button.setBackgroundResourses(R.drawable.yourimage);
```

it will set the default background of buttons.
and you can read more default properties of android widgets from given link:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

Drawable for "modern" button in XML is @android:drawable/btn_default_material
It does not exist in android.R.drawable for some reason.

EDIT: it's private, so don't use it.