# How to reset a button's background color to default?

Tags: android

I read a couple of posts but none of them had the working solution.

Once you do

```
button.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

How do you revert the button's background color back to default color?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a Button's background back to default (programmatically)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471932/how-to-get-a-buttons-background-back-to-default-programmatically)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

use:

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

Comment: button.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
button.setBackgroundColor(android.R.drawable.btn_default); This does not change the color back to the normal color

Comment: Oh Thank you so much!! I read android.R.drawable.btn_default before but I didn't know it was supposed to be setBackgroundResource. Thank you so much +1 to you everything!

Comment: this resets my button to a Android 2.3 version, how do I make it reset to android version default?

Comment: @Sartheris - Make sure in your manifest that the "target" is the new API you are aiming for (no reason it shouldn't be 19)

Comment: @Sean Setting the target in the manifest does not affect it. I can set both the target and the minimum to 4.0.3 (15), and it still resets the button to something like 2.3 (10).

Comment: doesn't work for Marshmallow material buttons either

Comment: This will set a yellow color on the pressed state for the button in API 27

Answer (score 21):

If the background color was set using

```
btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

it can be reset using:

```
btn.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

In contrast to `button.setBackgroundColor()` setting the color this way preserves the button's shape.

Comment: this answer worked better for me with appcompat api16+

Comment: for some reason this does not work for me when trying to change the background of an EditText. I wanted a way to change background of the input box, then reset it back to whatever it had originally. Setting the background color directly overwrites the original background drawable and there is no way to reset it without keeping a copy of the original.

Comment: clearColorFilter does not reset the color to the default grey, but to white.

Answer (score 10):

Nobody mentioned **TRANSPARENT** 
use it like this

```
findViewById(R.id.button_id).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Thank me later

Comment: great to know it helped.

Answer (score 5):

this worked better for me :

```
Button defbtn=new Button(this);
btn.setBackground(defbtn.getBackground());
```