# Closing application undoes last action

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have an alarm clock application, and I've just added code to exit the program when using the Back button from the main activity. However, when I do so, the last action the user took is undone. For example, if the user creates three alarms, then presses the back button, only two alarms will show up.

This is the Back button code, from Main Activity:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

And just in case, here's all the code from both activities I'm testing:

MainActivity.java (The only activity that has this Back button functionality, deliberately)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView alarmListView;
    ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList = new ArrayList<Alarm>();
    AlarmAdapter alarmAdapter;
    String filename = "alarmList";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        alarmListView = findViewById(R.id.alarmListView);

        // Credit to Mitch Woodbright for helping with this section, and other try/catch blocks.
        try
        {
            ArrayList<Alarm> alarm = (ArrayList<Alarm>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("alarmList");
            for(Alarm elements : alarm){
                alarmList.add(elements);
            }
            writeAlarmList(alarmList);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("AlarmList is empty.");
        }

        try {
            alarmList = readAlarmList();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }

        alarmAdapter = new AlarmAdapter(MainActivity.this, alarmList){
                @Override
                public void onUpdateClick(int position, ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList) {
                    super.onUpdateClick(position, alarmList);
                    Intent updateAlarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            CreateAlarmActivity.class);
                    updateAlarmIntent.putExtra("alarmList", alarmList);
                    updateAlarmIntent.putExtra("position", position);
                    startActivity(updateAlarmIntent);
                }
            };

      alarmListView.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);
      alarmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        alarmListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent updateAlarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateAlarmActivity.class);
                updateAlarmIntent.putExtra("alarmList", alarmList);
                updateAlarmIntent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(updateAlarmIntent);
            }
        });

       // writeAlarmList(alarmList);

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        alarmList = readAlarmList();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        alarmList = readAlarmList();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        writeAlarmList(alarmList);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        writeAlarmList(alarmList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Thanks to Mitch for this line.
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Create alarm when user presses FAB on activity_main.xml.
    public void createNewAlarm(View view) {
        Intent createAlarmIntent = new Intent(this, CreateAlarmActivity.class);
        createAlarmIntent.putExtra("alarmList", alarmList);
        startActivity(createAlarmIntent);
    }

    public void testAlarmActivated(View view){
        //Intent activateAlarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivatedActivity.class);
        //startActivity(activateAlarmIntent);
        while(alarmList.size() > 0){
            alarmList.remove(0);
        }
        Intent deleteEverythingIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        deleteEverythingIntent.putExtra("alarmList", alarmList);
        startActivity(deleteEverythingIntent);
    }

    public void writeAlarmList(ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(alarmList);
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<Alarm> readAlarmList(){
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList = (ArrayList<Alarm>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            return alarmList;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList = new ArrayList<Alarm>();
            System.out.println("File not found. Making empty list.");
            return alarmList;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList = new ArrayList<Alarm>();
            System.out.println("Null pointer exception. Making empty list.");
            return alarmList;
        }
        ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList = new ArrayList<Alarm>();
        return alarmList;
    }

}
```

CreateAlarmActivity.java (The activity which does the creating/updating/deleting of alarms)

```
public class CreateAlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // If the alarm is being created, position = -1.
    int position = -1;
    int alarmHour;
    int alarmMinute;
    boolean isPm;
    int snoozeTimer;
    int[] daysActive;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_alarm);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        alarmList = (ArrayList<Alarm>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("alarmList");

        try {
            // If we're updating an alarm, return the position of the alarm to update.
            position = (int)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("position");
        }
        // Else, keep going.
        catch (NullPointerException e){

        }

        Button hourButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonHours);
        Button minuteButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonMinutes);
        Button isPmButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonAmPm);
        Button snoozeTimerButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonSnoozeTimer);

        Button sundayButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonSunday);
        Button mondayButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonMonday);
        Button tuesdayButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonTuesday);
        Button wednesdayButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonWednesday);
        Button thursdayButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonThursday);
        Button fridayButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonFriday);
        Button saturdayButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonSaturday);

        // If creating a new alarm, initialise data as default.
        if (position == -1){
            alarmHour = 6;
            alarmMinute = 0;
            isPm = false;
            snoozeTimer = 10;
            daysActive = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        }

        // If updating an alarm, grab the defaults we already had.
        else {
            Alarm tempAlarm = alarmList.get(position);
            alarmHour = tempAlarm.hour;
            alarmMinute = tempAlarm.minute;
            isPm = tempAlarm.isPm;
            snoozeTimer = tempAlarm.snoozeTimer;
            daysActive = tempAlarm.daysActive;
        }

        // Set buttons to what they should be.

        hourButton.setText(Integer.toString(alarmHour));
        snoozeTimerButton.setText(Integer.toString(snoozeTimer));

        if (alarmMinute < 10){
            minuteButton.setText("0" + Integer.toString(alarmMinute));
        }
        else {
            minuteButton.setText(Integer.toString(alarmMinute));
        }

        if (!isPm){
            isPmButton.setText("am");
        }
        else {
            isPmButton.setText("pm");
        }

        setDayColor(sundayButton, daysActive[0]);
        setDayColor(mondayButton, daysActive[1]);
        setDayColor(tuesdayButton, daysActive[2]);
        setDayColor(wednesdayButton, daysActive[3]);
        setDayColor(thursdayButton, daysActive[4]);
        setDayColor(fridayButton, daysActive[5]);
        setDayColor(saturdayButton, daysActive[6]);

    }

    ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList = new ArrayList<Alarm>();

    // Add one to the hour of the alarm.
    public void changeHour(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonHours);

        if (alarmHour == 12){
            alarmHour = 0;
        }
        else {
            alarmHour++;
        }

        btn.setText(Integer.toString(alarmHour));

    }

    // Add one to the minute of the alarm.
    public void changeMinute(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonMinutes);

        if (alarmMinute == 59) {
            alarmMinute = 0;
        }
        else {
            alarmMinute++;
        }

        if (alarmMinute < 10) {
            // Ensure minute 1 becomes 01, e.g, 6:01 am.
            btn.setText("0" + Integer.toString(alarmMinute));
        }
        else {
            btn.setText(Integer.toString(alarmMinute));
        }
    }

    public void changeAmPm(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonAmPm);
        if (isPm == true) {
            isPm = false;
            btn.setText("am");
        }
        else {
            isPm = true;
            btn.setText("pm");
        }
    }

    public void changeSnoozeTimer(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSnoozeTimer);
        if (snoozeTimer == 15){
            snoozeTimer = 1;
        }
        else {
            snoozeTimer++;
        }
        btn.setText(Integer.toString(snoozeTimer));
    }

    public void finishAlarm(View view){
        EditText alarmName = findViewById(R.id.alarmName);
        String name = alarmName.getText().toString();
        Alarm alarm = new Alarm(name, alarmHour, alarmMinute, isPm, daysActive, snoozeTimer);

        // If we're creating an alarm.
        if (position == -1) {

            try {
                alarmList.add(alarm);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        // Else, we're updating one.
        else {
            try {
                // Set the alarm we're updating to the new alarm.
                alarmList.set(position, alarm);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        Intent finishAlarmIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        finishAlarmIntent.putExtra("alarmList", alarmList);
        startActivity(finishAlarmIntent);
    }


    public void cancelAlarm(View view){
        Intent cancelAlarmIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        cancelAlarmIntent.putExtra("alarmList", alarmList);
        startActivity(cancelAlarmIntent);
    }

    public void deleteAlarm(View view) {

        // If creating a new alarm, deleting is the same as cancelling.
        if (position == -1) {
            Intent cancelAlarmIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            cancelAlarmIntent.putExtra("alarmList", alarmList);
            startActivity(cancelAlarmIntent);
        }
        else {
            // Remove the alarm.
            alarmList.remove(position);

            Intent cancelAlarmIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            cancelAlarmIntent.putExtra("alarmList", alarmList);
            startActivity(cancelAlarmIntent);
        }
    }

    public void changeSunday(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSunday);
        daysActive[0] = switchDay(daysActive[0]);
        setDayColor(btn, daysActive[0]);
    }

    public void changeMonday(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonMonday);
        daysActive[1] = switchDay(daysActive[1]);
        setDayColor(btn, daysActive[1]);
    }

    public void changeTuesday(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonTuesday);
        daysActive[2] = switchDay(daysActive[2]);
        setDayColor(btn, daysActive[2]);
    }

    public void changeWednesday(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonWednesday);
        daysActive[3] = switchDay(daysActive[3]);
        setDayColor(btn, daysActive[3]);
    }

    public void changeThursday(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonThursday);
        daysActive[4] = switchDay(daysActive[4]);
        setDayColor(btn, daysActive[4]);
    }

    public void changeFriday(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonFriday);
        daysActive[5] = switchDay(daysActive[5]);
        setDayColor(btn, daysActive[5]);
    }

    public void changeSaturday(View view) {
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSaturday);
        daysActive[6] = switchDay(daysActive[6]);
        setDayColor(btn, daysActive[6]);
    }

    // Helper method to switch the daysActive from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0.
    public int switchDay(int day) {
        if (day == 0){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    // Helper method to set the color of a daysActive button when updating the alarm.
    public void setDayColor(Button btn, int day) {

        if (day == 1) {
            // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173936/how-to-set-background-color-of-a-view
            // Credit goes to EddieB for the below line.
            btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        } else {
            // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802354/how-to-reset-a-buttons-background-color-to-default
            // Credit goes to Ivo for the below line.
            btn.getBackground().clearColorFilter();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What you are getting on Logcat when you doing this

Comment: There's a lot of stuff. Would you like any particular filters, or just the entire logcat from the application?

Comment: Logcat from the application. When you are about to click make sure clear all previous logs.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EizWxPKF

Here we go. It automatically started a new log when I closed, then reopened the app. So I copied both logs.

Comment: Sometimes it does not exit or close application because of Activity instance. For that simply you can finish the activity `ActivityInstance.finish()` as you reach on last Alarm which will close your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesh! When you say "as you reach on last Alarm", where should that be in the program? I'm still fairly new to Android development, and don't fully understand the Android life cycle.

Comment: Your issue solved?

Comment: I was able to solve it by using this.finishAffinity() eventually. Thanks for the followup :)

Comment: Upvote the answer, It may help someone who really needs the same. :)

Comment: Yes, same exactly I had told you to finish your activity yesterday. Good luck. :)

Comment: I've created an answer which explained the solution I eventually found. I'm unable to upvote comments, however - sorry about that.

Comment: No problem buddy. :)

Answer (score 0):

For people from the future:

I ended up solving this by using the following:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finishAffinity();
    }
```

Source: [How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically)