# How to reset a buttons background color to the default grey?

Tags: android

There are already many similar questions on SO, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802354/how-to-reset-a-buttons-background-color-to-default), but the answers don't apply (anymore?).

This is how I create the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

This is how I change the color:

```
myButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(lightSalmon, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

So far, so good. Now I want to change it back to the default. This is what I tried so far:

```
myButton.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
```

makes the button background white instead of the default grey. Same as:

```
myButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
```

This completely changes the look of the button:

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

It does reset the color, but the button looks completely different. Also not what I want.

I found `setTint()` in the API, but I haven't tried it, because it requires API level 21 (I'm on 15). Is there a backwards compatible way for `setTint()`?

Trying to remember the default color programmatically doesn't work either, because `getColorFilter()` also requires API level 21. (`setColorFilter()`on the other hand was there since API level 1).

Another option I can think of is to just apply the default grey (if I can determine its value). But I fear this might be biased: The default grey might be different on other phones, with other Android versions, other themes and styles...

What other options do I have?

Comment: I think you should specify the theme you are using like `btn_default_normal_holo_light` to get the correct drawable resource (something like: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/UnifiedEmail/+/89e2c5b/res/drawable/btn_default.xml)

Comment: Could you expand on that? What do mean "specify the theme"?

Comment: It seems you are using API level 20 or lower... since android v4 there is a default theme named `HOLO` there is a chance that the color you are looking is dependent on this theme... please check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/R.drawable for reference and try to use `abc_item_background_holo_dark` or `abc_item_background_holo_light`

Comment: Yes, I'm on API level 15. How exactly am I supposed to use `abc_item_background_holo_dark` or `abc_item_background_holo_light`?

Comment: `myButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.abc_item_background_holo_light);`

Comment: That results in a compile error: Cannot resolve symbol 'abc_item_background_holo_light'.

Answer (score -1):

Use **TRANSPARENT**

```
findViewById(R.id.button_id).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

It should work.

Comment: it won't work. He want the default grey colour, not a transparent button

Comment: He is said default and this will change to the default color the application has which is grey right.
Have you tried running it once.